# regex remove white space and new lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to reduce the amount of new lines that a user can enter. If a user enters 3 or more new lines, it will replace to 2 `<br>`'s -

`txt = txt.replace(new RegExp('(\\n){3,}', 'gim') , '<br/><br/>');`

Problem is that if there's a space, or a tab etc. in between some br's then this regex will not match, so users can put \n\n space \n\n and it will look as though its 4 lines.

How do I change this regex, perhaps with a look forward / back to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work :

```
txt = txt.replace(/(\n[\t ]*){2,}\n/gm , '<br/><br/>')
```

It would replace any group of at least 3 `\n` with any number of `\t` and spaces in between.

Comment: @js-coder no because with `{3,}` you'd match also the spaces after the third `\n`.